# How do you update the Redux store on all devices running a react native app?

Tags: react-native, redux

In a react native app that has multiple users on separate devices, there is some data that varies depending on which user is logged in and other data which should be updated for all users on all devices. For example, if the users are able to submit posts they should be able to see and edit their own posts when logged in and this data would be different depending on which user is logged in on a device. Whereas an object containing all posts, should be updated for every user's app/device.

```
export default reducer = combineReducers({
    posts: postsReducer, // same for all users on all devices
    user: userReducer, // different depending on user on specific device
})
```

I am relatively new to redux and my understanding is that `store.dispatch` updates an app's store locally, on only the current device. However I want to know how to update data for every device which has the app downloaded.

Answer (score 1):

You should store your state properties inside an object, a map, in which each key will be represented by the users id and each value will be another object with your desired state.

So, your user reducer could look something like this:

```
type StatePerUser = {
    editPost: boolean,
    createPost: boolean,
};

type UserState = {
    user: { [userId: number]: StatePerUser },
    seePosts: boolean
};

const INITIAL_STATE = {
    user: {} // The key-value map for different users. Empty by default, you'll need to populate it when someone does login. 
    seePosts: true // All users should see posts
};

export default function reducer(state: UserState = INITIAL_STATE, action: *) { ... }
```

So workflow would be something like this:

- User does login, an entry is added to the users reducer, inside the `user` map (You can find better namings for those variables) with the user id acting as the key and your desired permissions object as the value. (values coming from your server)
- Then simply, when you want to check if some user has some specific permission/is allowed to do something, simply check the `user` map for the permissions, like `user[<CURRENT_USER_ID>].<PERMISSION_NAME>` and see if he is allowed to do that operation or not.

As a side note, I would maybe have this into 2 reducers, one `user` reducer containing information about the currently logged in user, and another reducer, maybe called `permissions/rights` where the above information would be stored.

Comment: So when using redux and updating the store, is it updated globally, for every user of the app on different devices?

Comment: Then I got your question totally wrong, or you asked it wrong. I thought you meant multiple users on the same device... So, no, updating the store on one device will update it on that device only, not for every user of the app on their devices.

Comment: Sorry, I misworded my question and have tried to clarify it.